# How to Normalize mp3 files across Multiple Folders/Albums With No Distortion

Tags: audio

What command-line tool can I use to to have all of my mp3s play at the same average volume? From what I understand, some tools are capable of setting all of the files in a given folder to the same volume. I assume these tools look at all of the audio files in the folder and find the average volume across all files before altering the individual files to match that average volume. But I want my thousands of files across hundreds of folders to have the same average volume.

I'm thinking of maybe there's something like a tool with an option to either pass a constant value which says "use this as the baseline instead of averaging out the volume of the files in this folder", or maybe one of its arguments can be a specific file to use to normalize all the rest to, and then I can use that same argument as I run the tool on every folder.

Also, I would prefer a tool which doesn't introduce any distortion. Is there anything like this?